# How to add a delay to a unity score

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in unity and i wanted to add an easy score system that would add +1 whenever u fit through a shape, after the first shape they all come at 1 second intervals, but there are 3 seconds untyil the first one.
My question is how do I make a downtime from the moment the level starts to the first shape?
Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText; 
    public float scoreCount;
    public float pointsPerSecond;
    public bool scoreIncreasing;

    void Update()
    {
        if (scoreIncreasing)
        {
            scoreCount += pointsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(scoreCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi what do you mean by "downtime"?

Comment: I want a way so that the timer could start after 3 seconds of starting the level itself

Comment: then use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html put a wait at the front for 3s, and then while needed do stuff, wait 1sec, repeat

Answer (score -1):

Time.time is already recorded as seconds, so make another float to track when the score should be kept, the value would be 3.00. If the total elapsed time passes that time, then track the score.

Comment: Perhaps provide some example code so we can follow more clearly?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you're making a Maze Runner-esque game? In which case you could have a conditional letting the system know when it can start converting time into points.
For instance, for the first 3 seconds you would have a boolean as "false," meaning the run hasn't started yet. Then after the elapsed time you change said boolean to "true."

So you would have your points added after 3 seconds. As for when you go through a 'shape' you could have those be collision based. if you've collided with the ring then +1 to points.
Though, personally, I would probably make it at least 5 or 10 points for getting said rings. Reward them for making the skill check!

Comment: I'm making a game that is more like Super Hexagon and I've been trying to make what u told me for the last 15 mins and i'm also very new to coding so i can't make it happen

Comment: No  worries, you would want something like this (based on yours from above):
`    public bool scoreIncreasing = false;`
`    public float startTimer = 3;`
`    void Update()`
`    {`
`        if (startTimer > 0){`
`            startTimer -= Time.deltaTime;`
`        } else {`
`            startIncreasing = true;`
`        }`
`    }`

Comment: i think i did it and i also enabled it in unity but it still doesn't work